# Save user redis

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis 6.2.5, and I'm facing some issues to save users.

It looks like it only works if I put the user in the `redis.conf` file. If I just create it with `acl setuser username` command and then restart the service, it loses the user information, even if I run the `save` or `bgsave` commands. Does anybody know a way to save the user definitely without editing the redis.conf file, or just add it in the memory but also on the `redis.conf` file, so, when it's restarted, the user will be there?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CONFIG REWRITE` command to rewrite the config file, so that your setting will be saved to config file. The next time, you start Redis with this config file, you'll get those user settings.

Also you can use an external ACL file to set ACL rules. If you want to change the settings, you can manually change the ACL file, and call `ACL LOAD` to reload the new configuration.

Check the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/acl) for detail.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the config rewrite command at the end, and that's why the user wasn't being saved properly.